# Feign Client does not proxy the methods inherited from interface if there are manually added ones

Tags: spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

In my project I have common module with API interfaces generated from OpenAPI spec:

```java
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen")
@Validated
@Tag(name = "Account Information", description = "Search and view customer accounts")
public interface AccountsApi {

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @RequestMapping(
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            value = "/accounts",
            produces = {"application/json"}
    )
    default ResponseEntity<Accounts> searchForAccounts(
            @Parameter(name = "accountIds", description = "Comma separated list of account ids", in = ParameterIn.QUERY) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "accountIds", required = false) List<String> accountIds
    ) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType : MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                    String exampleString = "null";
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", exampleString);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
}
```

There are two modules with Feign clients implementing this interface:

```java
//module A
@FeignClient(name = "accountClient", url = "${accounts.internal.api.url}")
public interface AccountsClient extends AccountsApi {
}

//module B
@FeignClient(name = "accountClient", url = "${accounts.internal.api.url}")
public interface AccountsClient extends AccountsApi {

    @GetMapping
    ResponseEntity<Accounts> getAccounts(@RequestParam("customerXRef") String customerXRef);
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the second client (in module B) proxies only the calls to `getAccount()` and for all the methods inherited from `AccountsApi` e.g. (`AccountsApi.searchForAccounts()`) returns 501 (`NOT_IMPLEMENTED`).

How can I fix this and have proxy for inherited methods either?

I use Spring Boot 2.7.17 and `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:3.1.8`.